# Memory transfer intel assembly AT&T

Tags: memory, assembly, x86, intel

I have a problem moving a string bytewise from one memory adress to another. Been at this for hours and tried some different strategies. Im new to Intel assemby so I need some tips and insight to help me solve the problem.

The getText routine is supposed to transfer n (found in %rsi) bytes from ibuf to the adress in %rdi. counterI is the offset used to indicate where to start the transfer, and after the routine is over it should point to the next byte that wasn't transfered. If there isn't n bytes it should cancel the transfer and return the actual number of bytes transfered in %rax.

```
getText:
        movq    $ibuf, %r10
        #in rsi is the number of bytes to be transfered
        #rdi contains the memory adress for the memory space to transfer to
        movq    $0, %r8     #start with offset 0
        movq    $0, %rax    #zero return register
        movq    (counterI), %r11
        cmpb    $0, (%r10, %r11, 1) #check if ibuf+counterI=NULL
        jne MOVE            #if so call and read to ibuf
        call    inImage
    MOVE:       
        cmpq    $0,%rsi         #if number of bytes to read is 0
        je  EXIT            #exit
        movq    counterI, %r9       
        movq    $0, %r9         #used for debugging only shold not be 0
        movb  (%r10, %r9, 1), %bl   #loads one byte to rdi from ibuf
        movb  %bl, (%rdi, %r8, 1)
        incq    counterI        #increase pointer offset
        decq    %rsi            #dec number of bytes to read
        incq    %r8         #inc offset in write buffert
        movq    %r8, %rax       #returns number of bytes wrote to buf 
        movq    (counterI), %r9 
        cmpb    $0, (%r10, %r9,1)   #check if ibuf+offset is NULL
        je  EXIT            #if so exit
        cmpq    $0, %rsi        #can be cleaned up later
        jne MOVE
    EXIT:
        movb    $0, (%rdi, %r8, 1)  #move NULL to buf+%r8?          
        ret
```

Comment: What are the semantics of this function supposed to be? What role does `counterI` play? What is `inImage`? Why do you zero-extend the byte you read and then write an entire qword? (that will write 7 extra zeroes at the end and just generally isn't necessary) Also if you're copying a string, you don't have to stop *before* the terminator and then add an extra terminator, you can just copy it and *then* detect if it was a terminator. You also pop something without ever pushed something / changed rsp, so it pops the return address and then returns into oblivion.

Comment: getText should transfer maximum of n bytes to the adress in register %rdi.  counterI is the current offset in ibuf. inImage is a function that writes from stdin to a string, in this case ibuf. 

The thing is that I tried to use movb but it complains when I try to put it in a %r# register.

I changed the push %r12 and didnt notice the pop :D Im more focused about the problem with moving from one memory adress to another correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
movq    counterI, %r9       
movq    $0, %r9         #used for debugging only shold not be 0
```

The second instruction makes the first useless but given the remark I understand you will remove it. Better still, you can remove both if you would change every occurence of %R9 into %R11.

```
movzbq  (%r10, %r9, 1), %r10    #loads one byte+zeroes to rdi from ibuf
movq    %r10, (%rdi, %r8, 1)    #HERE IS THE PROBLEM I THINK
```

Here is a dangerous construct. You're first using %R10 as an address but then drop a zero extended data byte in it. Later in the code you will again use %R10 as an address but sadly that won't be in there! The solution is to move into a different register and to not bother about the zero extention.

```
movb  (%r10, %r9, 1), %bl   #loads one byte to rdi from ibuf
movb  %bl, (%rdi, %r8, 1)
```

The following code can be shortened

```
 cmpb    $0, (%r10, %r9,1)   #check if ibuf+offset is NULL
 je  EXIT            #if so exit
 cmpq    $0, %rsi        #can be cleaned up later
 jne MOVE
EXIT:
```

as

```
 cmpb    $0, (%r10, %r9, 1)   #check if ibuf+offset is NULL
 jne MOVE
EXIT:
```